# How to get calltips with numpy (ex) in the geany editor

Tags: python, geany

I just build geany 1.23 under ubuntu 10.04.
If I write:

```
import numpy as np
```

then if I write:

```
np.
```

After writing the dot, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (nor <kbd>Tab</kbd>) doesn't trigger a calltip window as in ipython or with spyder.
Is it the normal behaviour or is there something to do to fix that?

thank you

jeanpat

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a global tags file [as described in the manual](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#global-tags) because Geany only comes with tags for Python standard libraries by default. I just put up [a NumPy tags file on the Wiki for you](http://wiki.geany.org/_media/tags/numpy.py.tags). Once you have this most of the symbols from the library should be available for auto-completion.